# MYSQL getting SUM through joins

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a possible solution that will give me TOP 3 users from `users` table who are ordered based on the `turnover` they made.

So here is my table schema for `users` and `transactions` table.

`users` TABLE

```
id     inviter_id
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
5      2
6      3
7      5
8      6
9      1
10     3
11     9
12     1
13     5
14     7
15     11
```

EXPLANATION : The `id` represents user's unique ID and `inviter_id` represents the ID that invited the user.

`transactions` TABLE

```
id            payer _id      amount
1             2              200
2             2              100
3             2              50
4             2              10
5             3              400
6             4              200
7             5              100
8             6              50
9             7              100
10            8              50
11            9              50
12            10             100 
13            11             400
14            2              200
15            2              100
16            2              50
17            2              10
18            4              500
```

Here `payer_id` represents the users in `users` table.

Desired Output :

```
user_id       turnover
//ID 1 should not be included in this table.
2             100         //ID 5 in `users` is referral of ID 2 so summing whatever ID 5 from `transactions` table using `payer_id` column we get : 100 (Sme process for other rows too)
3             150         //ID3's referrals : 6,10 | 50+100
4             0           //ID4's invited no one
5             100         //ID5's referrals : 7,13 | 100
6             50          //ID 6's referrals : 8 | 50
7             100         // ID 7's referrals : 14 | 0 (No rows for ID 14 in transactions table)
8             0           //No referrals invited
9             400         //ID9's referrals : 11 | 400
10            0           //No referrals invited
11            0           //ID11's referrals : 14 | 0 (No rows in txn table)
12            0           //No referrals invited
13            0           //No referrals invited
14            0           //No referrals invited
15            0           //No referrals invited
```

FIRST let me explain how I calculate `turnover` :

For each `id` from users table, Let's take id:1 as example. I check the 'inviter_id' column for 2. So whoever has the value as 2 in inviter_id column, those ids are considered as id 2's referral.
So I need the sum of `amount` all the referrals of id 2 has paid. Similarly for other ids and they should be sorted by the highest turnover.

What I tried so far :
here is my code.

```
        select u.id AS user_id, u.address AS address, SUM(turnover) AS turnover
        from users u left join
             (select ur.id, ur.inviter_id, SUM(mt.userTurnover) as turnover
                    from users ur left join

                            (select m.payer_id, SUM(m.amount) as userTurnover
                            from matrix m where m.created >= $content_start AND m.type = 'escrow'
                            group by m.payer_id
                            ) mt
                            on mt.payer_id = ur.id

                    where ur.created >= $content_start
              group by ur.inviter_id
             ) ui
             on ui.inviter_id = u.id
                 WHERE u.id != 1 AND u.id != 2 AND u.id != 3 AND u.id != 4
        group by u.id
        order by turnover desc  LIMIT 10;
```

I'm getting the sum of amounts of the user itself instead of the user's each and every referral's paid amount.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! Have the updated the question with comments explaining how the turnovers are added.

Comment: Where the values for `user_id` 7 and 8 are taken from? user 7 invites user 14 which have no payments, user 8 invites nobody.

Comment: Why there exists a self-inviting row for user `id=1` and not exasts for all another? (08aa51cef61d0945d035e36e2c3405e3)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. That was an error. I have updated all rows in desired output table. Since ID 1 is the first user his inviter is ID1 itself. Anyways the desired output table should not include ID 1

Comment: I'm glad you understood the question. @Akina

Comment: `I check the 'inviter_id' column for 2` Why 2?

Comment: To make it was I had to change it to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT u1.id, COALESCE(SUM(tr.amount), 0) turnover
FROM users u1
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u1.id = u2.inviter_id
LEFT JOIN transactions tr ON u2.id = tr.payer_id AND u2.id != u2.inviter_id
GROUP BY u1.id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3acff002e21f90720e949e4da83612b2)

If you need total payment sum for usrs.id = 1 (i.e. including self-referenced) then remove  `AND u2.id != u2.inviter_id`.

If you do not need the final row for users.id = 1 then add according WHERE condition.

Comment: Is it possible to get the count of referrals under each user id?

Comment: @YaseenHussain Of course, add according expression (COUNT(DISTINCT)) into the output list.